# What is the equivalent of SELECT <certain columns> in Flux Query Language?

Tags: influx-db

What would be equivalent flux query for `SELECT address, name FROM addresses` ? (I am referring to FluxQL, the new query language developed by InfluxData)

I didn't find a clear answer to this in the limited Flux Documentation present. Flux documentation says that `filter()` function is the equivalent of both `SELECT` and `WHERE` clauses, but all examples given are equivalent of `WHERE` clauses, nothing on `SELECT`.

Edit: An answer posted below gives the equivalent query in InfluxQL, which is not what I am asking for. Yeah I know, FluxQL, InfluxQL, it can get confusing.

These are the documentation for FluxQL for better reference:

https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.50/introduction/getting-started

https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/query-data/get-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abel Nightroad has posted a great answer to this, which you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60614957/4661264

Answer (score 0):

See [Writing and Exploring Data](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/introduction/getting-started/#writing-and-exploring-data) as part of the [Getting Started](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/introduction/getting-started/) documentation.

```
> SELECT "address", "name" FROM "addresses"
name: addresses
---------
time                              address            name
2020-03-09T07:51:07.580664347Z    123 fake street    Billy Bob

>
```

Comment: You are giving me a query in InfluxQL. I know about this. My question is about FluxQL, a new query language developed by InfluxData. These are the documentation for Flux: https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.50/introduction/getting-started/, https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/query-data/get-started/